# Git Workflow Between Local and Remote Deleting files removed from cache on push to Remote

Tags: git, git-workflow

I have been working with GIT for a while and it's obvious that I don't understand a core concept between local and remote.

I have a repo on bit bucket.

It's an old legacy app that requires yml files for configuration (Symfony 1.4.20)

I have a local version and there are two files that need to be a little different on local and remote.

I do the git clone and get the information that I need.

I change apps/frontend/config/factories.yml and config/databases.yml
and get everything working on my local system.

I then put these two files in my git ignore file and remove them from the cache.

When I remove them from the cache and do a git status it says those two files are marked for deletion.

If I commit them and then do a git push to the server it is constantly deleting those two files so when a new server is created it doesn't have two key configuration files.

I am obviously missing something extremely simple.

How do I change the files.
Keep a copy of the local changes
Remove them so GIT stops tracking them but does not delete them when I do a git push?

Happy to read other answers because I get the feeling this has probably been asked and answered but I haven't found one that makes sense to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have, rather unfortunately, kind of missed the point of `git`, and VCS in general. In most VCS models, `git`-like and otherwise, the general notion of an update operation is that both sets of files (local and remote) should be in the same state.

When you pull the files from your remote, then add them to your `.gitignore`, what you're telling `git` is, basically, "I'm no longer interested in tracking these files for some reason, so go ahead and don't include them in the repo from now on".

If there is a scenario in which different servers need different versions of these files, what that means is that they're a good candidate for automatic generation. Include a script in your repo that generates these files, and then add the files themselves to your `.gitignore`. That way, you're doing what `git` is *intended* to do - track source files that are the same for every environment. VCSs of any stripe aren't meant to track files that should be different across environments, and shouldn't be pressed into service trying to do such.

Comment: I can add a autogenerate to my aws script it is already making the nginx files.

Comment: And there you go. Just add the `.yml` files permanently to your `.gitignore`, call it a day, and head to the pub.